# How to lay out tooltip icon next to each radio button element

Tags: jquery, css

```css
   .cell { width: 60%; max-width: 70%;}
    
  
 #product-form .stock label{
   position: relative;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-align: center;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 80px; 
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 #product-form .stock label span{
 display: inline-block !important;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1rem;
   text-align: left;
   height: 10px !important;
   line-height: 10px !important;    
 } 
 
 #product-form .stock input:checked + label{
   border: 3px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
#product-form .stock input:checked + label:after {
   content: "\2713";
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -10px;
 }

#product-form .stock input{
 display: none;
}        
      
.help-tip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    z-index: 999;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { 
        opacity:0; 
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }

    100% {
        opacity:100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
 <form id="product-form">
  <section class="stock">
   Choose your material:  
<input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='5' value='5'><label class='5-label cell' for='5'>ABC<div class='help-tip'>
    <p>tooltip ABC</p>
</div></label><input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='1' value='1'><label class='1-label cell' for='1'>DEF)<div class='help-tip'>
    <p>Tooltip DEF</p>
</div>
</label>
  </section>
    </form>
```

I want to place a tooltip icon next to each radio button element (which isn't styled as a radio button) so that clicking it will not select the radio button

I have tried putting the tooltip code outside the radio button element code but it doesn't appear in correct position.

See for the full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/6fq2Le09/

```
<form id="product-form">
  <section class="stock">
    Choose your material:
    <input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='5' value='5'><label class='5-label cell' for='5'>ABC<div class='help-tip'>
        <p>tooltip ABC</p>
    </div></label><input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='1' value='1'><label class='1-label cell' for='1'>DEF)<div class='help-tip'>
        <p>Tooltip DEF</p>
    </div>
    </label>
  </section>
</form>
```

This is where I have reached. The problem is that clicking the tooltip icon is also selecting the radio button.  I just want to click the icon and display the relevant tooltip.

Expected result:
Clicking the tooltip should only display the tooltip and not select the radio button (turn the option green)

TIA!

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: remove the `for` attribute fom your label if you do not want it to target the input - or just change it to a span - please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Also you are not allowed a div or a p inside a label so you should probably change the label to a div anyway

Comment: @Pete Better to just move the tooltip target outside of the label; labels are good practice, both from a semantic and an accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the icon outside of the `label` element.

I've also added a wrapper to each `input`/`label`/`help-tip` combination to make it easier to keep them aligned. Adding `display: flex` to that wrapper does that. Removing the absolute positioning (but adding relative positioning) for the `help-tip` elements keeps the tooltip state working fine.

```css
.cell {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 70%;
}

#product-form .stock label {
  position: relative;
  color: #2fcc71;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#product-form .stock label span {
  display: inline-block !important;
  color: #2fcc71;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  height: 10px !important;
  line-height: 10px !important;
}

#product-form .stock input:checked+label {
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  color: #fff;
}

#product-form .stock input:checked+label:after {
  content: "\2713";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}

#product-form .stock input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.help-tip {
  /*
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -30px;
  */
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #BCDBEA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before {
  content: '?';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.help-tip p {
  /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1E2021;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: -4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  z-index: 999;
}

.help-tip p:before {
  /* The pointer of the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #1E2021;
  right: 10px;
  top: -12px;
}

.help-tip p:after {
  /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}


/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="product-form">
  <section class="stock">
    Choose your material:
    <div class="radio-wrapper"><input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='5' value='5'><label class='5-label cell' for='5'>ABC</label>
      <div class='help-tip'>
        <p>tooltip ABC</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-wrapper"><input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='1' value='1'><label class='1-label cell' for='1'>DEF)</label>
      <div class='help-tip'>
        <p>Tooltip DEF</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

I will note that the icon is now top-aligned rather than bottom-aligned, relative to the "label". If that's an issue, simply add `margin-top: 56px` (height of "label" - height of icon).

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the click propagation event oh the tooltip div.

```
<div class='help-tip' onclick="return false;">
...
</div>
```

```css
.cell { width: 60%; max-width: 70%;}
    
  
 #product-form .stock label{
   position: relative;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-align: center;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 80px; 
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 #product-form .stock label span{
 display: inline-block !important;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1rem;
   text-align: left;
   height: 10px !important;
   line-height: 10px !important;    
 } 
 
 #product-form .stock input:checked + label{
   border: 3px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
#product-form .stock input:checked + label:after {
   content: "\2713";
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -10px;
 }

#product-form .stock input{
 display: none;
}        
      
.help-tip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    z-index: 999;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { 
        opacity:0; 
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }

    100% {
        opacity:100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

```html
<form id="product-form">
   <section class="stock">
      Choose your material:  
      <input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='5' value='5'>
      <label class='5-label cell' for='5'>
         ABC
         <div class='help-tip' onclick="return false;">
            <p>tooltip ABC</p>
         </div>
      </label>
      <input type='radio' name='radio_stock' id='1' value='1'>
      <label class='1-label cell' for='1'>
         DEF)
         <div class='help-tip' onclick="return false;">
            <p>Tooltip DEF</p>
         </div>
      </label>
   </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I add 
       $( ".help-tip" ).click( function( event ) {
         event.preventDefault();
       } );    - changing this to return false; did the trick